# How to hide past events posts based on custom end date field

Tags: php, wordpress, function, datetime

Im using this code for sorting posts by a custom date field. "start date" = (dato_for_arrangementet)

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {
    
    // do not modify queries in the admin
    if( is_admin() ) {
        return $query;
    }

    // only modify queries for 'event' post type with order by date
    if( isset($query->query_vars['post_type']) && (is_array($query->query_vars['post_type']) && in_array('event', $query->query_vars['post_type'])) && $query->query['orderby'] == 'date')  {
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value');    
        $query->set('meta_key', 'dato_for_arrangementet');     
        $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
    }

    // return
    return $query;
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts'); type here
```

Q: if i add another custom field "End Date" how can i hide posts based on this enddate?

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters